# How can I combine 2 complex mysql queries

Tags: php, mysql

So I have two MySQL queries that if I had the knowledge to combine I would but I don't so that's why I turned to "SO", and in that case I haven't tried anything because its out of my scope. I want to combine all in one query and if that's not possible please let me know.

Query one "This selects all of your friends posts including yours":

```
"SELECT b.*, c.photo, d.name, e.status 
FROM post b 
INNER JOIN profile c 
INNER JOIN user d 
INNER JOIN user_friendship e 
ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
AND b.from_user = d.id 
AND e.friend_id = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = :status 
AND e.user_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 20"
```

Query two "This selects all of the people your following posts":

```
"SELECT b.*, c.photo, d.name, e.status
FROM post b
INNER JOIN profile c 
INNER JOIN user d 
INNER JOIN user_follower e 
ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
AND b.from_user = d.id 
AND e.to_id = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = :status 
AND e.who_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 20"
```

**I have combined these but with php alone. I'd like to combine both in one single MySQL query**. Thanks in advance

Comment: How about just using a simple `UNION/UNION ALL`?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson still not familiar with that but since the first answer used that i guess I'm going to have to use that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM
  (SELECT b.*,
          c.photo,
          d.name,
          e.status
   FROM post b
   INNER JOIN profile c
   INNER JOIN USER d
   INNER JOIN user_friendship e ON b.from_user = c.user_id
   AND b.from_user = d.id
   AND e.friend_id = b.from_user
   WHERE e.status = :status
     AND e.user_id = :id LIMIT 20
   UNION SELECT b.*,
                c.photo,
                d.name,
                e.status
   FROM post b
   INNER JOIN profile c
   INNER JOIN USER d
   INNER JOIN user_follower e ON b.from_user = c.user_id
   AND b.from_user = d.id
   AND e.to_id = b.from_user
   WHERE e.status = :status
     AND e.who_id = :id LIMIT 20 ) MainQuery
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Comment: I think you may to add an `ORDER BY` outside the `UNION` itself, I suspect you may lose the ordering otherwise.

Comment: doesn't matter i will organize with php by timestamp @JoachimIsaksson

Comment: Just add collumn to determinate from query is result and for sorting. Have a nice day :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer VoonArt It was exactly what i was looking for thanks again and you too have a great day

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT b.*, c.photo, d.name, e.status, "P" 
FROM post b 
INNER JOIN profile c 
INNER JOIN user d 
INNER JOIN user_friendship e 
ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
AND b.from_user = d.id 
AND e.friend_id = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = :status 
AND e.user_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 20
UNION
SELECT b.*, c.photo, d.name, e.status, "F"
FROM post b
INNER JOIN profile c 
INNER JOIN user d 
INNER JOIN user_follower e 
ON b.from_user = c.user_id 
AND b.from_user = d.id 
AND e.to_id = b.from_user 
WHERE e.status = :status 
AND e.who_id = :id
ORDER BY b.id DESC LIMIT 20
```

With the extra column you can see where the row is coming from (P = post, F = following)

Keep in mind that union will remove duplicate rows. If you want to see all rows use `UNION ALL`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, both of the answers I received were correct and helped me. Unfortunately I had to go with the other answer because it was first but i still up-voted your answer thanks again barry